# Getting wrong height for UITextView using boundingRectWithSize:options:context

Tags: ios

I'm getting the wrong height for an UITextView even I'm calculating its size like this:

```
CGRect requiredHeight = [self boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                           context:nil];
```

When I add the height to my frame I can see all text but not the last line. I don't know why. (text was a `HTML` before I transformed it into a `NSAttributedString`).

Comment: Try to check your string for unexpected characters in it.

Comment: let me check @EvgenyKarkan But it is a french string that I receive from server

Comment: it doesn't seems to be the problem. I removed all non common characters and I still get the wrong size. @EvgenyKarkan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so, the answer es very obvious but not always we see things like that so easily!.

**EXPLANATION:**

The answer is if we need to get the height for an specific field (it could be label, textView, etc) we should use a method from those fields to calculate its height, due to they could have some specific properties, if we calculate the height from a text (not considering the field) we are not considering those special properties the field could have.

**SHORT ANSWER:**

So short answer, for `UITextView` you should use `[textView sizeThatFits:]` to get its height, it's probably the best way to do it if you are not using `auto layout`.

*advice:
I encourage you to use `autolayout` if you can easily migrate your UI.*

Comment: `sizeThatFits` returns an accurate height where `boundingRectWithSize` was not. Thanks!